# Regarding "rep inflation" from the recalculation and actions that require certain amounts of rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

[Now that apparently we're all going to be getting some sweet rep](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) (or at least those of use who have asked positive questions), is there going to be any change to the rep required for, as an example, [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)? I can see myself suddenly getting a significant chunk of rep, and that may push me past the 25k boundary required for "Access to site analytics". I'm not any more knowledgeable than I was prior to the calculation though, so does this make sense?

Are rep boundaries like those for the association bonus, privileges, commenting etc. going to be adjusted? Or is this adjustment meant to more accurately reflect the site knowledge associated with asking a good question, so no change will happen?

Comment: And it begins...

Comment: `I'm not any more knowledgeable` I'm not sure that _knowledge_ is relevant. I think the privileges are based on the level of _trust_ that SE has decided to place in users that have hit a certain reputation target. And if they're bumping people up with new rep, then I think it means they implicitly trust you with those (potential) new privileges.

Comment: *"or at least those of use who have asked positive questions"* and those who have asked negative questions that haven't been deleted yet. essentially any question that received an upvote will gain as long as it didn't have more than 5 times as many downvotes.

Comment: @WebHead: I'm not sure *trust* is relevant.  Anyone can gain significant rep from simply asking a lot of questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So? If you ask a _lot_ of questions and you're getting reputation from them, then... yes, the platform trusts you know enough about using the platform to have more privileges for using more parts of the platform. They're literally called "privileges". They are not called "answer rewards".

Comment: The fear I have is of some of the asinine edit requests I've rejected. Some of them were just flat out terrible, and sometimes, the user never learned (eg I rejected multiple requests from the same user of the span of months who was obsessed with adding tags to titles).

I can't wait to get a bunch of crap from 10 years ago bumping to the front page because someone added a comma to text.

Comment: Automatically giving people privileges based on totally unrelated activities may not have been SE's best decision, but it doesn't seem horrible in practice.

Answer (score 23):

I don't think recalculating the boundaries will be necessary since they're already pretty arbitrary - it's not as though a 19k user is clueless as to how the site functions, and magically transforms into a power user once they hit 20k rep.

If there is a concern that users that shouldn't have access to certain privileges are being given access all of a sudden, I would argue that a data-driven approach should be taken, involving evaluating both the correct thresholds for privileges and reputation values for various actions.

In my opinion, this would be overkill - but it's better than inflating all the reputation requirements by some random percentage for fear of the masses getting access to privileges, say, 20% sooner.

Comment: The low boundaries seem important though... e.g. up- and downvoting and comments

Comment: @DavidW Is it important that people who ask good questions progress more slowly towards upvoting and downvoting privileges than people who give good answers? I'm not sure, but I can't think of a reason why this would be beneficial..

Comment: Personally I'd set the threshold for voting a little higher (probably for both cases) and keep comments where they are. I guess my feeling is that an upvoted answer has probably actually helped someone, whereas an awful question is often upvoted because "I had this problem too"

Comment: But I guess my point was more that we probably aren't really worried about the 19k->20k boundary, but should be at least thinking about the first few tiers. I'm not exactly sure either though

Comment: @Cowthulhu I think there are a lot more "me too" or "cool idea" votes on questions than on answers. This change makes it more likely that people who've been taught by example that "me too" votes on poor-quality questions are appropriate will get voting privileges and propagate that voting style forward. That said, sand brings in more advertising dollars than pearls do, so it makes sense we'd start optimizing for that instead.

Comment: @manveti speaking from experience, people do not hesitate to downvote bad questions, and bad questions don't get upvoted (even if they reach a bunch of people) ;). My (super embarrassing) question from 7 years ago with 25k+ views is still sitting at a stable -3, despite (I would assume) helping many newbies.

Comment: @Cowthulhu I see plenty of pity-upvotes, and on sites like Worldbuilding there are a lot of upvotes on way-too-broad questions about something cool. The issue is that this change means that your -3 question may well still be a net rep gain (e.g. if it's 4 downvotes and 1 upvote, it'll be -3 but net +2 rep) -- as long as a question does better than 1 upvote per 5 downvotes it's a win.

Comment: @manveti I don't have the data to agree/disagree with that, fair point!

Comment: I'm reminded by a an observation from the designer of a much more sophisticated reputation system used on a different platform: the majority of your good-faith users cannot be confused about what an action means. Only the designer can be confused about what the users think it means.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think those reputation requirements are going to be changed;

> For those of you that are getting new privileges: we ask you to take the responsibility reverently. You are the question experts. You are the people that can identify a question that is struggling and you know how hard it can be to on the other side of that keyboard. Thank you in advance for gently coaching question askers through their experience.

That's directly from the blog post, and it really seems to convey that **the requirements are going to be suddenly much easier to achieve due to the recalculation.** Hopefully, as a community, we can be responsible with our new privileges.

Comment: Yes, I just reread the blog post and caught that. I didn't think it skimmed it that poorly on the first read, but apparently I did.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Still, good to get it out in writing for the community's benefit. :)

Comment: But if your rep is decreased, you can lose access to those privileges[.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339225/does-the-suspension-penalty-get-reinstated-when-the-op-deletes-the-profile-and-c)

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya I don't believe it's possible to lose reputation from an increase in the value of an upvote. Downvotes didn't change in value, right?

Answer (score 13):

As this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/357753/davidw) says, the boundaries for privileges at the low end, e.g., for up voting, flagging, down voting, etc., are likely more important to consider possibly changing. Now, by asking just one or two questions with some positive up votes, it'll be that much easier to get those privileges than before.  I suggest considering increasing some of these, although I'm not sure what an appropriate amount would be.

However, one thing I think should be increased is for up voting. Also, as  [snakecharmerb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/397555/snakecharmerb)'s  [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338112/regarding-rep-inflation-from-the-recalculation-and-actions-that-require-certai/338116?noredirect=1#comment1125387_338116) says, the threshold for "protected" questions should possibly be bumped up, say to 20, with the later [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338112/regarding-rep-inflation-from-the-recalculation-and-actions-that-require-certai/338116?noredirect=1#comment1125439_338116) making several good points in favor of this, e.g.,

> ... it not only stops very new users from adding low quality answers to popular questions, it also *protects* them from the consequences of doing so: downvotes and answer deletion. So upping the the protection limit would help new users onboarding experience I think. (Also, it would prevent the protection privilege, which requires *15,000* rep to earn - from being completely devalued.)

Also the minimum reputation of 5 for "participate in meta", can now be achieved even with a net negative score, so perhaps it should be increased to 10 or so as well, to make it more appropriate. Finally, if they're considering examining the reputation system, perhaps some privileges that are currently combined at one level, e.g., "Post more links, answer protected questions", should now have different privilege levels.

Comment: The threshold on "protected" questions might possibly be an area of concern - maybe it could be bumped to 20?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I probably won't be too worried about "participate in meta". As with everything it deserves a bit of thought, but I suspect it's unlikely to be too abused

Comment: @DavidW I'm not overly worried about the "participate in meta" privilege either, but I think it should be considered if it's still appropriate, along with at least most of the other lower-level privileges. There are members here on this meta site, and overall in SE, who have far more experience & knowledge than I do regarding what might be best. Unfortunately, from past experience, I don't think that SE is very likely to listen to them very much, if at all. Nonetheless, I still hope they do consider it and, if they possibly make some changes, I also hope it'll have an overall positive effect.

Comment: Expanding on protected questions: on SO protected questions can only answered by users with > 10 rep.  This is a low bar but it not only stops very new users from adding low quality answers to popular questions, it also _protects_ them from the consequences of doing so: downvotes and answer deletion.  So upping the the protection limit would help new users onboarding experience I think.  (Also, it would prevent the protection privilege, which requires _15,000_ rep to earn - from being completely devalued.)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you for your suggestions. You made several excellent points. I've updated my answer to include part of what you wrote.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I doubt it makes much of a difference if a new users needs 2 question upvotes or 1 to contribute to a protected question. That bar is really only there to guard against *entirely* new users.

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica yes, it's not that big a deal, but still worth some consideration I think.  There was a recent, inconclusive,  discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390907/we-need-better-tools-to-prevent-long-tail-of-crap-on-popular-questions)

Comment: Meta is one of our primary support channels, so ideally it wouldn't have a rep requirement at all. In reality, the main reason "participate in meta" is even a privilege with a rep requirement is because it's fairly common for folks to get confused and post programming questions on MSO instead of SO at first.

Comment: Similarly, the rep needed to answer a protected question is there to prevent spam answers from brand new users. If someone really wants to answer a protected question and goes to the trouble of asking a question that is worth upvoting... that's a net win for everyone, really.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for your feedback & details. One point you mention is "... goes to the trouble of asking a question that is worth upvoting... that's a net win for everyone, really". My concern is that if people upvote questions the same as before, it'll be that much easier to get enough reputation, even with poor questions, than before. It'll be interesting to see, and I hope I do at some point, how question upvoting changes from now on compared to before today.

Answer (score 11):

At this time, we don't have plans on our roadmap to adjust privileges.

Our moderators are aware that people will be receiving new privileges.

If we, or our moderators, discover anything concerning from the data we're monitoring, we will evaluate our next steps.

Answer (score 8):

As a moderator - with a *few* exceptions, on a healthy site, with a good number of additional mods - its not *that* likely to matter.

On the *broad* scope of things - users who matter, either being exceptionally good, or requiring a fair amount of babysitting are actually relatively small compared to our overall userbase on SU or even MSE (which has been getting a lot more of my attention the past few weeks).

Practically - the *worst* users, who have their posts at zero or negative score, won't likely benefit too much from it. The rare user who has successfully managed to grind asking questions to reasonable reputation *might* - but from my experience, these are monumentally uncommon.

So practically speaking - hopefully I don't foresee much issues that I wouldn't have seen anyway. It's as much about the people as the numbers