# Why was the reputation change not announced on this meta site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta, announcements

I'm aware that there was a blog announcing the reputation change, but I only just came across [the meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/3367799). I was surprised to see it on the SO meta rather than here because it affects all SE sites.

I did search the post, but only found a comment speculating why it was posted there:

> I see why they made this into a banner and a blog post, instead of a post in meta.stackexchange.com : they knew we wouldn't like it, and we can't downvote blog posts into oblivion. – Ismael Miguel [yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers#comment740565_391250)

Is that really the reason why it wasn't posted on this meta site? If not, then why? Is there a new policy to make announcements in these blogs from now on?

Comment: There was a banner posted on every site telling users of the imminent change, I think, if I recall correctly, that it also included a link to the blog article by Ms. Chipps.

Comment: You are asking us to speculate about the thought processes of SE management? This seems like more stirring of the pot without purpose.

Comment: There has been several posts leading to the change, so users on MSE were "mentally" prepared. Related: 1. [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337843) and 2. [Is it harder to write a good question or a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337654) and 3. [Regarding “rep inflation” from the recalculation and actions that require certain amounts of rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338112)

Comment: It seems that Sara became a bit shy about posting at Meta SE, given her recently not so well received posts here.

Answer (score 33):

The essential point is a different one: it really didn't matter *where* this announcement was made.

The real point: before the public announcement, there should have been an *internal* one, here on MSE. Ideally, not only an announcement, but a proposal asking for feedback!

I agree with the other answer, there are good reasons to make the final announcement on the blog. But that final announcement should not have been the first time the community learned about this.

Beyond that, I agree with the comments: asking about the actual motivation of SE Inc. can only result in guessing and speculation. I suggest to not put energy into such activities. The stuff we can directly observe is annoying enough already.

Answer (score 18):

From what I can tell, the policy has historically been to announce major system changes on the blog. This stretches back from the Jeff Atwood days until around 2015.

Since 2016, the team has generally been announcing changes here on this meta site. However, in my view, this has presented a problem: whenever newer users are linked to this meta site, they often don't realize that they've been linked to a different site (due to the same design elements), and go on to ask their (off-topic) question here. Whenever something new is announced here, I often see a spike in off-topic questions here that we have to moderate. (One of those spikes was *so* big such that the reputation requirement to ask questions here had to be raised to 2 from 1.)

Personally, for this reason, I prefer such announcements to be on the blog.

Comment: Makes sense. But then it would be nice to include a link with the blog post that points to the preceding discussion on meta.

Comment: But we didn't even have Meta SE back in the days. Everything was on SO meta and then later large parts of SO meta got exported here.

Comment: @Lundin Not quite. The site today known as Meta.SE was previously known as Meta.SO, and still had its own separate rep. In April 2014, the site was renamed and redesigned, and a whole new per-site meta was established for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

The announcement in the Meta Stack Overflow post that you cite is not an official announcement by the company. It is just a local moderator posting something informative. Since that author doesn't work for Stack Exchange there was no obligation, or even expectation, to post at all.

Given that this was apparently a purely voluntary action, and indeed a favor to the community, there are two logical reasons to have posted it on Meta Stack Overflow:

1. Stack Overflow *is* that moderator's community.
2. An announcement of this sort is likely to receive many downvotes. Indeed, the question currently has a score of -317. On Meta Stack Exchange those downvotes translate to lost reputation. On Meta Stack Overflow there is no independent reputation, so there is no danger in posting something unpopular.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338518/why-was-the-reputation-change-not-announced-on-this-meta-site#comment1128028_338518

Answer (score 9):

One possible consideration would be the fact that there's [only two Featured MSE post slots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/132874) in the sidebar, and those two slots are currently being held by [Feedback post: Moderator review and reinstatement processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336177/132874) and [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/132874). Announcing a network-wide change on Meta would probably be ineffective without Featuring, and effective Featuring would require de-Featuring one of the others. Announcing it via the blog doesn't have that issue, since blog posts get their own sidebar slots.