# I have gotten one upvote for a question, but 10 points were awarded. How come?

Tags: discussion

Look here:

[image]

And now here:

[image]

Can you see what I mean? One upvote, 10 points. I can remember though that at first 5 points were awarded, which changed into 10. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple: SE Inc. decided to change the policy throughout the network to give 10 reputation for questions and answers.

Their reasons are outlined in their blog at https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

This has also been discussed (after the fact) here on MSE. You can see some of that at [Why was the reputation change not announced on this meta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338518/why-was-the-reputation-change-not-announced-on-this-meta-site/338524) for example. Or, if you want to know what people here thought about that change you can to [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337843/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-increased-network-wide)

Finally, after a few weeks it already feels pretty normal. Now I very much doubt that this change caused any significant change to the number of questions asked.

But there was no clear measurable goal attached to that change, so nobody needs to explain whether such goals were met or not.

Comment: OKAY! Now I understand why my reputation suddenly went that high!