# Does the suspension timer continue to increment after an account is deleted?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

On [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean/125271#125271),

> If the account holder creates a new account to bypass the suspension, that new account will also receive the same suspension period as the previous one, even if the old account was deleted.

Additionally, on https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current, it says (for suspended users only):

> While you are suspended from the site, we recommend that you take a break from the site and come back with a clear mind. We will not prevent you from deleting your profile if you still wish to do so, but do know that creating a new profile will automatically reinstate the remaining time of the previous suspension.

---

So, does the suspension period pause when the account is deleted and then reinstated when the new profile is created, even if the new profile is created after the 7/30/365-day period?

Let's say, one user received a 365-day suspension on August 16, 2019.  He/she deletes his/her suspended profile on November 27, 2019, when there are 262 days left in the suspension (as it expires on August 15, 2020).  The user creates a new profile on August **20**, 2020. There are two possible ways to interpret these quotes:

- The newly created account will receive a 262-day suspension, which will end on May 9, 2021.
- The newly created account will not receive any automatic suspension, as it was created after the original suspension expired.

Which interpretation is correct? Does the user still re-receive the suspension, which now would expire on a different date?

Comment: Curious questions about suspensions, bans, etc. tend to be downvoted, because people often believe without fully reading that the question is about an existing suspension and you're hiding details, asking how to evade it, etc.

Comment: The OP in this case does appear to have been suspended from Music.SE with a suspension expiry date of August 15, 2020, so it's likely that they have a more than idle interest in the actual mechanics of this. This doesn't make it a bad question - it's a quite interesting one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.

*Practically* the suspension counter keeps running after you deleted your account.

Lets say you're on a 30 day suspension. You wait 2 days, and go ....ehhhh and delete your account. Then wait 5 days and make a new account - you're on 23 days (30-7). Presumably, this will happen as long as the new accounts are linked to the old one.

As such, if you deleted at any time between day 1-30, and waited for the suspension to pass, your suspension would be over.

You might get in trouble for other things I guess but you won't be suspended.

Comment: `You might get in trouble for other things I guess but you won't be suspended.` and within the hour *This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Dec 27 at 4:20.* that escalated quickly.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica You've just witnessed the rare *"triple threat suspension"*: Being suspended on three separate SEs simultaneously for three separate amounts of time (week, month, year).