# Are developers/moderators keen on adding new reputation achievements?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I recently joined Stack Exchange, and have seen the reputation "achievements" or privileges and having access to tools, e.g., moderator tools at 10K rep.

And I also have seen many people with hundreds of thousands of reputation on many sites or even a few million on the main Stack Exchange site. Are the moderators/developers of SE keen or thinking of adding new achievements/privileges for e.g. 50K rep? Or are there no more "tools" to add?

The last attempt to formulate something for 30K was [in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get).

**Edit:**

Should privileges be added for e.g. voting, flagging, editing? - suggested by @Oleg_Valter_is_with_Ukraine

Comment: Last attempt to formulate something was done in [2015 for 30K users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get)

Comment: @rene focus on "attempt", yeah. :/

Comment: This [answer from Staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338149/282094) says that "adjusting" privileges isn't on the roadmap; you might take that to mean that adding new ones isn't either.

Comment: What is the feature request here? What should be added/changed?

Comment: @VLAZ we've come to a state where anything will do. Anything.

Comment: @VLAZ discussions about new features are often also tagged as feature request as it's implied they ask for such features to be added. Here it's pretty obvious the intention is to add new reputation achievements/privileges, but it's also fine to have only discussion tag, I'm neutral about it so won't roll back the tag removal, for example.

Comment: Can we please just stop dishing out privileges based on passive income accumulation (aka naive capitalism approach)? The only thing it represents is the ability to flood the respective sites with posts of at least a bearable quality. How about giving privileges for actions that really matters (flagging, reviewing, editing, voting)?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine You can put that as an answer, I think its a good idea

Comment: In order to address an on-site problem through rep-gating, we must first identify an on-site problem that can be addressed by rep-gating... Of course, this is only my personal opinion, but I'd be inclined to say that in comparison to using more salient metrics for to grant privileges, rep-gating privileges often causes more problems than it solves. Tread lightly, this is dangerous ground. ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thing is, there's isn't much difference in experience between a 10k and a 30k user (I've even seen people mentioning 3k as a low limit, because that's when you can cast close votes.) So there's no real motivation to give them extra abilities on the site; of course, there are [other incentives (temporarily paused)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195/295232). Also, on some sites it's really hard to reach 30k (or even the equivalent ~6k on a beta site) - on Community Building, there is [only one non-moderator](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) with access to the Trusted user tools and Site analytics.

So unless there is a very specific tool which is either too dangerous when not used properly (but then it's usually limited to staff and/or ♦ moderators), or too computationally expensive to be released to too many users, it's IMHO not likely that it will be added as a reputation-based privilege. But who knows ...

Random thought: when you gain (much) reputation from answers, you'll earn gold tag badges and get more privileges in the form of the [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders?noredirect=1&lq=1). There have been some discussions about doing something like that for silver tag badges holders as well.

Answer (score 4):

On-site privileges tied to reputation currently max out at 35k, because that's when you get 30 delete votes per day, the maximum (see the [moderator tools privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). At 100k you're put on the waiting list for swag. Beyond that, you merely have the knowledge that you could create 200+ bounties with the largest amount of reputation (500), or 2,000+ at the lowest amount (50). You might also get gold tag badges which allow you to single-handedly close questions with that tag as duplicates. (However, it's possible to unlock these without having all the other privileges — I'm speaking as a [proud gold tag badge holder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/discussion?userid=6083675) with only 5k rep.)

With new features, privileges have been given at existing privilege levels, otherwise too few people would be able to access them. SO Documentation (RIP) was the first example I remember, which had [3 new, separate privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356564/6083675). The [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377768/323179) is planned as part of the review queues privilege, unlocked at 500 rep (though it's not clear if this will be part of the existing privilege or a new one).

Sometimes new features take away from privileges instead: Having an expanded user card used to be a part of the 1k privilege and now it's available to everyone who has an About Me. Moderator Tools is essentially another example, since now it's not necessary to have that to see all your deleted posts (which was an absolutely essential change — the privilege still gives a lot, including a nicer way to see a list of your deleted posts).